# Calling an activity from jquery in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am new to cordova so wanted to know if it is possible or not.

I have a functionality to implement, which I think I will be more comfortable in android native activity.

So can I call the native android from an html page or through jquery and the vice versa.

Comment: yes. It is possible.
you just need to create a cordova plugin which opens your intent/Activity.

Comment: can you please provide some links or samples.

Answer (score 0):

You need binding JavaScript code to Android code (bridge)
See official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is a good tutorial

http://itsmycodeshare.blogspot.in/2016/01/create-custom-cordova-plugins-using.html

and this is basic plugin example which interacts with js from Android java

https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello

add your further activity and other code in `<plugin_name>.java` in src folder.